# How can I add two probabilities with the same time?

Tags: probability

When I have two probabilities at the same time or at different time how can I add them together? I know that simply add them doesn't work because that is just for two probabilities independent or mutual exclusive. Do I need to normalize the two probabilities? Why can't I simply add them together? Is there a reason?
With two probabilities I mean I've two dice with 6 side. When the probability of dice 1 and side 1 is 1:6 and it's the same for dice 2 how can I combine them together? There is this rule about mutual exclusive or independent but I also have read about the other rule of the same time. Is there a probabilities that both dice have the same side at the same time?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by adding up two probabilities? Do you mean adding up the probabilities of two different events?

Comment: For mutually exclusive adding is correct for finding probability that (at least) one of $A$ or $B$ happens. For independent, adding is essentially always wrong.

Comment: I don't understand a thing. I'm lost.

Comment: This question is really unclear.  I don't understand what you mean by "time".  Can you give a concrete example, stating exactly what you are trying to find?  Your phrase "combine them together" is ambiguous.

Comment: Is order ok for you? Order of probabilities?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to combine the probabilities, you have to decide what event you want.  If you want the chance that both dice come up $1$, the events are independent and you multiply them:  $\frac 16 \cdot \frac 16=\frac 1{36}$.  If you want the chance that either one comes up and they were exclusive, you would add them.  In this case they are not exclusive-both dice can come up $1$.  The chance that at least one of them comes up $1$ is $\frac 16 + \frac 16 - \frac 1{36}=\frac {11}{36}$  The subtraction of $\frac 1 {36}$ is because we have double counted the case where they both came up $1$-it is part of both $\frac  16$'s.

Comment: What does it mean both come up 1? Come up first? I've read this answer here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184115/in-need-of-tips-suggestions-when-to-add-or-multiply-probabilities?rq=1.

Comment: @Skidrow:  you said you were rolling two dice.  The order doesn't matter, just the number each one shows.

Comment: What if my dice is different size? A cube and a tetraeder? And I've also normalize the probabilities can I add them together? Why do I need to normalize them?

Comment: If you have a d6 and a d4, the chance of a 1 on the d6 is $\frac 16$ and the chance on the d4 is $\frac 14$.  If you ask what is the chance they are both 1, it is $\frac 1{24}$  If you ask what is the chance of at least one 1, it is $\frac 16 + \frac 14 - \frac 1{24}=\frac 38$ by the same logic.  You should get a basic probability book, which can explain this in much better detail.

Comment: @Bytemain when you calculate probabilities of events it's easier to think of them as unions and intersections of finit sets. Ross-Millikan showed a sieve formula were you have to add the unions (include) and then subtract (exclude) the intersecting part to not count it twice. The math is described by the [inclusion and exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: @Doomjunky: Thx a lot!